# Infinite scroll in react.js not working, I am using infinite scroll component and it is not loading images from next page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, infinite-scroll

I am new to React.js and I am learning, I am trying to fetch more images from the flicker API when I scroll down but it is not working,

I am using material UI and Infinite scroll component library for it.

This is what I have done far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { CardMedia } from '@material-ui/core';
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

export default function Images() {
  var cardStyle = {
    display: "block",
    transitionDuration: "0.3s",
  };
  const [data, setdata] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  // const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  async function loadPhotos() {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=1583ada955f818856c5692be7cb57c4e&per_page=12&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    const data = await json.photos;
    const photo = await data.photo;
    setdata(photo);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    loadPhotos();
  }, []);
  
  function handleLoadMore() {
    setPage(page => page + 1);
  }
  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={data.length}
      next={() => handleLoadMore()}
      hasMore={true}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {data.map((photo, index) => (
          <Grid item xs={4} key={index}>
            <Card>
              <CardContent style={cardStyle}>
                
              <CardMedia
  style={{ height: "300px" }}
  component="img"
  image={`https://live.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${photo.secret}.jpg`}
/>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
}
```

Here is the newest one :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { CardMedia } from "@material-ui/core";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

export default function Images() {
  var cardStyle = {
    display: "block",
    transitionDuration: "0.3s"
  };
  const [data, setdata] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  

  async function loadPhotos() { 
  const response = await fetch(`https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=1583ada955f818856c5692be7cb57c4e&per_page=12&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`); 
  const json = await response.json(); 
  const datap = await json.photos; 
  const photo = await datap.photo; 
  setdata([...data, photo] ); 
} 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadPhotos();
  }, [page]);

  function handleLoadMore() {
    setPage(page => page + 1);
  }
  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={data.length}
      next={() => handleLoadMore()}
      hasMore={true}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {data.map((photo, index) => (
          <Grid item xs={4} key={index}>
            <Card>
              <CardContent style={cardStyle}>
                <CardMedia
                  style={{ height: "300px" }}
                  component="img"
                  image={`https://live.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${photo.secret}.jpg`}
                />
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your useEffect should have as a dependency the page number so it triggers the loadFunction again.

```
useEffect(() => {
 loadPhotos();
}, [page]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried it but it's not loading, the images are changed and not added below, and that too only on the first scroll.

Comment: Your setter updates with the new images. If you want to keep them, spread the previous data and add the new data. 

    setdata(...data, photo);

Comment: I have tried it earlier, I get this error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: Change your local state variable to some other name. data is also defined inside the loadPhotos

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the error, but now on scroll, I am getting this one: typeError: data.map is not a function
Images
src/Components/api.js:43
  40 |   hasMore={true}
  41 |   loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
  42 | >
> 43 |   <Grid container spacing={2}>
     | ^  44 |     {data.map((photo, index) => (
  45 |       <Grid item xs={4} key={index}>
  46 |         <Card>

Comment: Sorry, setdata([...<your new variable>, photo]) . It needs to be wrapped by an array

Comment: Thanks, I am not seeing the error now but the images are still not loading, and also the infinite scroll is not working, I have added the modified code to my original question, please check if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: setdata([...data, photo]);

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your willingness to help, but I have added that the issue still exists and the console is responding with undefined for the data fetched.

Comment: Nope, please check my last comment, I have edited it.

Comment: async function loadPhotos() { const response = await fetch( `https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=1583ada955f818856c5692be7cb57c4e&per_page=12&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1` ); const json = await response.json(); const datap = await json.photos; const photo = await datap.photo; setdata([...data, photo] ); }   replace your function by this code

Comment: Probably the image URL is not built correctly. Inspect your DOM, copy the URL and try to open in a new browser tab

Comment: No, the Image URL is correct, because it was working earlier, I have inspected it and the issue is ${photo.id} and other variables are outputting undefined for the URL https://live.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${photo.secret}.jpg

Comment: Update your code exactly like you have right now please. In your last modified version you still missing the square brackets when updating the state. Should be setdata([...data, photo] ) . Notice the square brackets []

Comment: I have updated the code with the newest one, the second code is the newest one, I have also mentioned it there.

Comment: async function loadPhotos() { 
  const response = await fetch(`https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=1583ada955f818856c5692be7cb57c4e&per_page=12&page=${page}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`); 
  const json = await response.json(); 
  const newPhotos = await json.photos; 
  
  setdata(prevState => [...prevState, newPhotos] ); 
}. Try this

Comment: Nope, still same issue.

Comment: console.log() the data variable after scroll please and past it here. Put the console.log after the data state declaration

Comment: I am getting an array correctly:
page: 1
pages: 84
perpage: 12
photo: Array(12)
0: {id: "51273164352", owner: "53919301@N06", secret: "8677eeb346", server: "65535", farm: 66, …}
1: {id: "51273912451", owner: "7221539@N06", secret: "fa551c3616", server: "65535", farm: 66, …}

Comment: You are not populating correctly the state. You don't care about the '1 pages...' part. Just pass to the state the array of photos.

Comment: const photo = await datap.photo.photo; this should work by looking at that log

Comment: I have tried that too but fetch response of the, by the way ,${photo.id} and other variables are outputting undefined for the URL live.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${photo.secret}.jpg  Thanks for your help.

Comment: const [data, setdata] = useState([]); console.log('I wanna see this data', data); show me this log after scrolling

Comment: I think, the console is giving response right, this is the console response: I wanna see this data 0: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
3: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 4